# Sharepoint - Project Management - Grouping of tasks

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, project-management, gantt-chart

I have a question regarding Sharepoint 2010. I create a new site with site template for Project Management. I am using Gantt chart on Sharepoint and most of things were intuitive and easily configurable. The only point which is left and I have not been able to do is -  Grouping the tasks in Gantt Chart.

I am looking for something like the way its on Slide#11 at http://www.slideshare.net/ASPE_INC/building-a-project-management-information-system-with-sharepoint.

I am going nuts searching this on web. Can anyone guide me. Is it possible to implement task grouping ?

**edit on feb-11-2013**
I tried few things and found that Under New Item there is an option to add "Task" and "Summary Task". Summary task seems to be the group I have been looking for. So this is good, but now I don't know how to add a task under this summary task :P

Comment: I tried few things and found that Under New Item there is an option to add "Task" and "Summary Task". Summary task seems to be the group I have been looking for. So this is good, but now I don't know how to add a task under this summary task :P

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to just create a sub task/category/phase or some logical column and in the gantt view group on that.

You don't get the fancy project management features, but have to add for each predecessors and such, but then you can view tasks and subtasks in the same view.